# Advanced SELECT query (HAVING)

Tags: mysql, select, having

I have the following theoretical database:

Hotel(**Hotel_No**, Name, Address)
    Room(**Room_No**, **Hotel_No**, Type, Price)
    Booking(**Hotel_No**, **Guest_No**, **Date_From**, Date_To, Room_No)
    Guest(**Guest_No**, Name, Address)

Bold attributes serve as the primary keys for that table.

The goal is to find the most commonly booked room type for each hotel in London. The expected end output in my head is the following, where `Hotel_No` is the id of a unique hotel in London, and `Type` is the type of room a hotel offers:

```
+----------+----------+-------+
| Hotel_No |   Type   | Count |
+----------+----------+-------+
|       67 | Single   |    53 |
|       45 | Double   |    67 |
|       32 | Double   |    23 |
|      ... | ...      |   ... |
+----------+----------+-------+
```

Bookings are counted as the reservations within the bookings table, with each row representing one booking.

The answer I was given is the following:

```
SELECT Type, H.hotel No
FROM Room R, Hotel H, Booking B
WHERE R.Hotel_No = H.Hotel No 
AND H.Address LIKE '%London%'
AND B.Room No = R.Room_No 
AND H.Hotel_No = B.Hotel_No 
GROUP BY Type, H.hotel_No
HAVING Count(*) >= ALL(
    SELECT Count(*)
    FROM Booking B2,Room R2
    WHERE B2.Hotel_No = H.Hotel_No 
    AND R2.Room_No = B2.Room_No 
    GROUP BY R2.Type);
```

Is this solution correct?

I am having trouble understanding how the nested query is managing to select the highest Type of hotel booking by hotel in London, rather than simply returning the row or rows with the highest booking by type, aggregated over all hotels in London.

Why do we create a new table in the nested query, B2, and R2, but still reference the original H table?

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Hotel (
  Hotel_No INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Hotel VARCHAR(10),
  Address VARCHAR(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (Hotel_No)
);

CREATE TABLE Room (
  Room_No INT NOT NULL,
  Hotel_No INT NOT NULL,
  Type ENUM('Single', 'Double', 'Family'),
  PRIMARY KEY(Room_No, Hotel_No),
  FOREIGN KEY(Hotel_No) REFERENCES Hotel(Hotel_No)
);

CREATE TABLE Booking (
  Hotel_No INT NOT NULL,
  Guest_No INT NOT NULL,
  Date_From DATE NOT NULL,
  Room_No INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Hotel_No, Guest_No, Date_From),
  FOREIGN KEY (Hotel_No) REFERENCES Hotel(Hotel_No),
  FOREIGN KEY (Room_No, Hotel_No) REFERENCES Room(Room_No, Hotel_No)
);

INSERT INTO Hotel (Name, Address) VALUES 
('Hotel A', 'London'),
('Hotel B', 'London'),
('Hotel C', 'London'),
('Hotel D', 'Birmingham');

INSERT INTO Room VALUES
(1, 1, 'Single'),
(2, 1, 'Double'),
(1, 2, 'Single'),
(2, 2, 'Double'),
(3, 2, 'Family'),
(1, 3, 'Single'),
(2, 3, 'Double'),
(1, 4, 'Single'),
(2, 4, 'Single');

  INSERT INTO Booking VALUES
  (1, 1, '2000/01/01', 1),
  (1, 2, '2000/02/01', 1),
  (1, 3, '2000/01/01', 2),
  (1, 4, '2000/02/01', 2),
  (1, 5, '2000/03/01', 2),
  (2, 6, '2000/01/01', 1),
  (2, 7, '2000/01/01', 2),
  (2, 8, '2000/01/01', 3),
  (2, 9, '2000/02/01', 3),
  (2, 11, '2000/01/01', 1),
  (3, 12, '2000/01/01', 2),
  (3, 13, '2000/02/01', 2);
```

Comment: How are you measuring bookings?  Are you counting reservations or number of acual days stayed?

Comment: Sorry, bookings are counted by simply counting the number of rows found within the bookings table, so just reservations. I will edit my main post.

Comment: @Olivier i can get it to further detail if you can provide the sample data and table definitions

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I have created sample data. Please let me know if this is sufficient.

Comment: @Olivier i have updated my answer with brief i hope that makes sense

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thank you, it makes it a lot clearer. I am still a little confused however, as to how the subquery manages to count the bookings of a particular `Type` for each `Hotel_No`, rather than returning a count of total bookings for each hotel type existing, given that the subquery is only grouped by `Type`

Comment: Its not returning a count of all bookings for hotel it is returning the highest count between different room type for each hotel in sample data set in my answer you can see  for hotel 1 there 2 counts for different room types but in sub_query column it contains the highest count for hotel between room types

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161625/discussion-between-olivier-and-m-khalid-junaid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution looks fine, In main query your tables are joined and grouped by hotel and type i believe type comes from rooms table, Based on this grouping you can get the count of bookings per hotel and room type which may give you more than one rows for each hotel depends on the booking of room types that belongs to hotel.

The sub query part is just to pick the rows from above query which have the highest count for each hotel, So if hotel A has following count

```
A single 10
A double 15
```

then second row will be returned for  hotel A because it has highest count. Same logic goes for each hotel.

> Edit for sample data

I have tweaked your posted query to get the hotels and room types with maximum count which is as below.

```
SELECT TYPE, H.hotel_No,COUNT(*) 
FROM Room R, Hotel H, Booking B
WHERE R.Hotel_No = H.Hotel_No 
AND H.Address LIKE '%London%'
AND B.Room_No = R.Room_No 
AND H.Hotel_No = B.Hotel_No 
GROUP BY TYPE, H.hotel_No
HAVING COUNT(*) >=  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Booking B2,Room R2
    WHERE B2.Hotel_No = H.Hotel_No 
    AND R2.Room_No = B2.Room_No
    AND R2.Hotel_No = H.Hotel_No 
    GROUP BY  R2.Type
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
    LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY H.hotel_No
```

the original correlated sub query was missing with another filter to match which was `R2.Hotel_No = H.Hotel_No` then an `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` and `LIMIT 1` to get the highest count for each hotel, If is isn't used you will have no data because count of booking excluding room types will be higher as compare to count of bookings per hotel and room type.

So back to question here is what sub query is doing. For each row of parent query the result of subquery can be seen [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d5344/3)

```
TYPE    hotel_No  COUNT(*)  sub_query  
------  --------  --------  -----------
Single         1         2            3
Double         1         3            3
Single         2         2            2
Double         2         1            2
Family         2         2            2
Double         3         2            2
```

In above as you can see For hotel 1 there are 2 rows for room type single booking count is 2 and for room type double booking count is 3 while if you see the result of sub_query   in next column the count 3 for both rows. So if you compare the count and result of sub query one by one for hotel 1 first row will be excluded because single booking count is less from the max count. Same logic goes for other rows.

Final result set

```
TYPE    hotel_No    COUNT(*)

1   Double  1   3
2   Single  2   2
3   Family  2   2
4   Double  3   2
```

In final result set you can see there for hotel id 2 there are 2 records for different room type because they both share same highest count

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/NLK58500)

Comment: How exactly does the subquery work? Is there any chance you could elaborate on how it manages to pick out the highest count for each hotel? Wouldn't the group by clause simply pick out the count with the highest Type, aggregated over all hotels?

Comment: For my personal knowledge then why don't use a max in a subquery ?

Comment: @Olivier 'Wouldn't the group by clause simply pick out the count with the highest Type, aggregated over all hotels? ' - No, because of the `WHERE B2.Hotel_No = H.Hotel_No` clause in the subquery

Comment: @MartinSchneider Is there no need to match B2.HotelNo = R2.HotelNo?

Comment: The room has a HotelNo, the booking has a HotelNo and a RoomNo. The booking is therefore related to the hotel 1) through its own HotelNo and 2) through the HotelNo of its room. B2.HotelNo = R2.HotelNo should be superfluous

Comment: @Olivier the sub query counts the no. of bookings per hotel if you see this part `B2.Hotel_No = H.Hotel_No`  its matching hotel no from parent query and grouping criteria in sub query is just `R2.Type`, So in having clause of parent query `Count(*) >=` it will select the rows which has count greater or equal to , to the returned count from sub query hope it makes sense

Comment: @DanielE. using `max` on what ? if applied on count may be you can get the max count but about the type of room it will be indeterminate

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I think I see where this is going but I'm having a hard time grasping this visually. Why did we match the `B2.Hotel_No = H.Hotel_No` rather than `B2.Hotel_No = H2.Hotel_No`? I'm still struggling to understand how it can select the highest `Type` by `Hotel_No` rather than just selecting the highest row or rows aggregated over all `Hotel_No`. Thanks for your persistence!

Comment: @Olivier its better if you can provide sample data using http://sqlfiddle.com/  so that i can have a better look for this, Also for your query related to `B2.Hotel_No = H2.Hotel_No`, If you see there is no aliase named as `H2` because hotel table is defined only once in query,  the purpose `B2.Hotel_No = H.Hotel_No` of this it matches hotel from parent query in sub query to get the count for each hotel

Comment: Thank you. I will try to work through this some more and come back with sample data if I still don't understand.

Comment: @MartinSchneider Just to clarify, what about the case where hotels can have the same `Room_No`? Without specifying `R2.Hotel_No = B2.Hotel_No`, how would SQL know where to match `R2.Room_No = B2.Room_No`?

Comment: i was assuming that Room_No is a primary key and therefore unique across all hotels

Comment: @MartinSchneider Ok, so am I correct in assuming that since the table `Room` has a composite primary key of `Hotel_No` and `Room_No`, this is not the case and we need the aforementioned `R2.Hotel_No = B2.Hotel_No`?

Comment: yes that's right. and as nearly every participant in this posting has stated: if you would provide more sample data we could help you better :-)

Comment: @MartinSchneider I have created sample data. Please let me know if this is sufficient.